# Drupal 7, execute mySQL query oncick of a button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, drupal-7

I have a local Drupal 7 website and an article with a button in it.
I want, when the button is clicked to run a MySQL query and save username and email of the user who clicked the button.
Can I do this with JavaScript? This is the html of the button and the js script I have created at the bottom of the article edit:

```
<button id="test" value="test" onclick="Press()">Press Here</button>

<script>
function Press() {
    var test= document.getElementById("test");
test.innerHTML="Thank you";
localStorage.value=("ok");
}
</script>
```

Comment: "Can I do this with JavaScript?" - no, you'll have to write php code to interact with the database.

Comment: Ok, so can you give me further information on that? Is there a function or a specific code that I have to use? I don't know php that well...

Comment: Writing a PHP web service is one thing. Writing it for Drupal is another. I recommend you to read some documentation or a good book about Drupal.

Comment: @ArgirisA You can create a module that will respond to link click. But you won't be able to write a module if you don't know php well.

Comment: Sadly, that's true...